# cache invalidation on WPEngine when theme options are changed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

due to changes with how Jupiter theme in Wordpress generates theme css files, for example: https://www.nasta.no/wp-content/uploads/mk_assets/theme-options-production-1548757908.css?ver=1548757865 (this file is controlling page width, logo, menus, footer, fonts and more). Our website use this css file as references and it is invalidated every time changes are made in Wordpress.

Notice how the filename includes a unix timestamp which is generated every time a change in css/theme related options are made in Wordpress.

Because our site scrapes the content of nasta.no and refreshes every 10 minutes or so, whenever changes are made in Wordpress, our site tries to reference an old theme-options-production.css file that has been deleted and replaced with a newer version. The result is that our site will always lag behind at maximum 10 minutes and try to serve css files that no longer exists.

The page works fine until someone "Clear Theme Cache" or do changes in "Theme Options" (we/Nasta will try to stay away from doing this until you have found a solution).

A possible solution from my end can be to shorten the intervals when you scan through nasta.no after changes, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

Do you have any other approach ?

In nasta.no site - How they solved it there 
Another problem in the same vain is cache invalidation on WPEngine when theme options are changed. 
With Jupiter, when updating Theme Options by either clearing the theme cache, or making changes, the old CSS file for theme-options.css is deleted and a new one is generated with a unix time suffix. 
Because WPEngine have its own proprietary caching solution, no cache purging was done after a new CSS was created.

To allow for purging of cache for WPEngine, the following change was made:

```
function mk_clear_cache_plugins() { 
    if ( function_exists( 'w3tc_pgcache_flush' ) ) { 
        w3tc_pgcache_flush(); 
        // echo 'W3 Total Cache: Page cache flushed'; 
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'wp_cache_clear_cache' ) ) { 
        wp_cache_clear_cache(); 
        // echo 'WP Super Cache: Page cache cleared.'; 
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'rocket_clean_domain' ) ) { 
        rocket_clean_domain(); 
        // echo 'WP Rocket: Domain cache purged.'; 
    } elseif ( method_exists('WpeCommon', 'purge_varnish_cache') ) { 
        // WPEngine specific purge 
        WpeCommon::purge_varnish_cache(); 
    } else { 

    } 
    // die; 
}
```